# Error in printing a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{


  int c, i, wspace, others;

  int digits[10];

  wspace = others = 0;

  for (i=0; i<10; i++){

    digits[i] = 0;

  }

  while ((c =getchar())!=EOF){

    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){

      ++digits[c-'0'];
    }

    else if ( c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){

      ++wspace;
    }

    else {

      ++others;
    }

    printf("digits: %s", digits);
    printf("whitespace: %d, others: %d", wspace, others);

      }}
```

In the above stated code, I am trying to count the number of digits, whitespaces, and other inputs. However, when I am running the program it is printing 'digits' repeatedly. The program works fine if I put the data type of digits[10] as 'char' and use a 'for loop' to print it. I can't find whats wrong with my current way of doing it.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i < 10; ++i) printf( "digit %d : %d\n", i, digits[i]);`

Comment: I want to make it work using 'char' and '%s' and it is giving me repeated printing of 'digits:' when I am running it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `digits` is an arry of type `int`. You cannot use `%s` format specifier to print an `int` array. You've to print the elements one-by-one using a loop using `%d` format specifier.

As per `C11` standard document, chapter 7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function

> s
>
> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a *pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.*

OTOH, if you change the `digits` to be an array of type `char`, you can use `%s`. No need to use loop to print one-by-one in that case.

Note: An array of `int` is not a *string*.

---

Edit:

Even if you change the `digits` array to type of `char`, you may not get the desired output while printing out the array using `%s`. Remember, `0` and `'0'` are not the same.

- `0` is having ASCII value of `0`, which represents `nul`.
- `'0'` is having an ASCII value of `48` which represents a *character* `0`.

Solution: As per the current approach, you've to print the `int` elements one-by-one using a loop using `%d` format specifire.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the code, it is 'char' not 'int', and I am still getting an error, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @diplodocus Please do not change the question in a way that make the existing answer appear wrong.

Comment: I know the difference you mentioned in your recent edit, but how is that causing the problem? Repeated values of 'digits:', where is the link?

Comment: So there is no other way than going the 'int' way here?

Comment: @diplodocus you cannot use `%s`, use a for loop and use `%d`.